# Change jenkins directory path in OSX. Settings JENKINS_HOME did not work

Tags: macos, jenkins

I have an old jenkins installation in an OS X (version 10.11.3). Today I tried to access it and it showed a welcome message without any jobs or plugins installed.

Apparently directory path its pointing to **/Users/my_user/.jenkins** and after some search for my old jobs they are located at **/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs**.

I tried settings JENKINS_HOME to /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home and restarting jenkins but without any success. I also search around, but nothing seems to be changing the home directory of jenkins.

Any tip?

Comment: How did you start jenkins, start from Tomcat or simply just `java -jar`?  Also, have you verified the `Home directory` which shows at the top of `http://jenkins_url/configure`, was it still ` /Users/my_user/.jenkins` ?